# When we should use do?

Tags: haskell

Sometimes the program shows an error if I don't use do. But it runs well without do sometimes. 
ex:

```
countdown ::Int -> IO ()
countdown x =  if x <= 0 
               then putStrLn "The End."
               else putStrLn (show (x))
```

runs well 
But

```
countdown ::Int -> IO ()
countdown x =  if x <= 0 
               then putStrLn "The End."
               else putStrLn (show (x)) 
                    countdown (x-1)
```

shows error

Comment: You never need do. In fact `do` is just syntactical sugar.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Short answer:** line breaks don't mean "next statement" in Haskell, like they do in many mainstream languages, like Python, Ruby, and recently even JavaScript.

---

**Long answer**

First, let's get rid of the `if`. It only clouds the issue:

```
countdown1 :: Int -> IO ()
countdown1 x = putStrLn (show x)

countdown2 :: Int -> IO ()
countdown2 x = putStrLn (show x)
               countdown (x-1)
```

Notice that the type of your function is `IO ()`. That's the type of what the function must ultimately calculate. Or "produce", if you will. This means that whatever is on the right of the equality sign must be of type `IO ()`.

```
countdown x = .........
              ^       ^
              +-------+
                  \
                   the type of whatever is here must be `IO ()`
```

The first version, `countdown1`, does satisfy this, because the expression `putStrLn (show x)` is, indeed, of type `IO ()`

The second version, `countdown2`, on the other hand, looks very strange to the compiler. It looks like you're trying to call `putStrLn`, and you're trying to pass it three parameters: `(show x)`, `countdown`, and `(x-1)`.

Don't let the newline between `(show x)` and `countdown` confuse you: as mentioned above, newlines don't mean "next statement" in Haskell. This is because in Haskell there is no such thing as a "statement" in the first place. Everything is an expression.

But wait! If newlines don't count as "next statement", then how the hell do I tell Haskell to perform several actions in order? Like, for example, first do `putStrLn`, and then do `countdown`?

Well, this is where monads come in. Monads (of which `IO` is a prime example) were specifically brought into Haskell for this very reason: to express order of things. And the primary operation for that is *"bind"*, which in Haskell exists in the form of an operator `>>=`. This operator takes a monadic value (such as `IO Int` or `IO ()`) on the left, and takes a function that returns a monadic value (such as `Int -> IO String`) on the right, and "glues" them together. The result is a new monadic action, which consists of the two input actions executed one after the other.

Applying this to your example with `putStrLn` and `countdown`, it would look like this:

```
putStrLn (show x) >>= (\y -> countdown (x-1))
^               ^     ^                     ^
+---------------+     +---------------------+
    \                        \
     first monadic value      a function that takes the result of the
                              first action as parameter and returns
                              the second action
```

But this is a bit inconvenient. Sure, you can glue together two actions, maybe even three. But after a while this becomes very messy. (at first I had an example here, but then decided to do without; just trust me: it does get messy)

So to relieve the mess, the language now offers syntactic sugar in the form of the `do` notation. Inside the `do` notation, newline *does*, in fact, mean "next statement", and these consecutive "statements" get desugared into a sequence of calls to the `>>=` operator, giving them the semantics of "executing in order". Something like this:

```
do
  y <- f x
  z <- h y            ====>      f x >>= (\y -> h y >>= (\z -> g x y z))
  g x y z
```

So to the naked eye the `do` notation does look roughly equivalent to multiple-line program in Python, Ruby, or JavaScript. But underneath it all, it's still a pure functional program, where everything is an expression, and the order of (non-pure, effectful) operations is explicitly controlled.

---

So, to summarize: you need to use `do` in your program to express the order - first `putStrLn`, and then `countdown`:

```
countdown :: Int -> IO ()
countdown x = if x <= 0 
              then putStrLn "The End."
              else do
                     putStrLn (show (x)) 
                     countdown (x-1)
```

But you *don't* need to use `do` when there is just one operation, so there is no order to speak of.

And if you don't want to use `do` for whatever reason, you can desugar it manually into the equivalent `>>=` call:

```
countdown :: Int -> IO ()
countdown x = if x <= 0 
              then putStrLn "The End."
              else putStrLn (show (x)) >>= \_ -> countdown (x-1)
```